# What adjustments to the new site theme should we request?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, meta

As you're all aware, Stack Exchange has implemented a unified theme structure across all network sites, which impacted the appearance of Biology Stack. (See [Biology updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3874/16866) for the initial announcement and some early feedback).

[image]

<sup>New</sup>

[image]

<sup>Old</sup>

A handful of us provided some [initial feedback](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3873/16866), and I noticed some consistency in some of that feedback. Although Stack Exchange has made clear that the overall theme and it structure are not up for further discussion, after reaching out to SE staff, they've let me know that **we can request minor modifications on Meta (*ala* [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/309922))**

In the interest of creating a community-driven response (instead of just my own), I'd like to use this post to gather feedback regarding the new layout so that I (or someone else) can pass them along in a succinct and community-informed Meta request.

Note from [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/309922):

> **While the layout** (where the elements are, the existence of the left navigation, etc) **is fixed**, **we're happy to work with sites to get their specific designs/artwork more in line with what they want** - within the layout restrictions - and understanding that it will take us a bit to get to the changes.

Let's do this like we vote for [Community Promotion ads](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3784/16866):

### Create a simple answer post with your thoughts, and posts that get a positive upvote score of >6 can be passed on.

<sup>Note: please read the linked [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/309922) to get a feel for what *can* and *cannot* be requested.</sup>

Comment: I would prefer to have the site title bigger - more like it was in the old version.

Comment: We'll see this regardless of voting. ;) Don't forget, you may have two competing answers that both get +6, so deciding which may require more thought than just basing things on score alone. :D Probably also a good idea to avoid looking at downvotes, as not everyone is equally interested in downvoting and others don't have the ability to do so.

Comment: @theforestecologist It's a matter of time at the moment. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: @Catija thanks for the post! Makes sense; and I figured quite bit of subjectivity would complicate this. Glad to know that this Bio.Meta post alone can serve the purpose instead of having to compile further. Does that mean you all will react more to discussion vs upvotes/downvotes? -- in other words, how will SE gauge what should and shouldn't be modified/updated?

Comment: That's sort of subjective, and limited by what we *can* implement. If it looks like it has support and we can do it, we probably will. If either of those is missing, we don't. There is also a design element, in that we have designers who have their own aesthetic, so if what you come up with doesn't fit that exactly, they may adjust it if we do choose to implement it.